# Selecting from two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE Player
(playerID CHAR(3) ,
name CHAR(36),
year NUMBER,
team CHAR(50),
totalNoms NUMBER,
awardsWon NUMBER)
```

How can I create a query that will select from two columns (the team and the no of players) from the database?

Comment: not sure if I understand your question, is "no of players" a column in table "Player"? If it isn't please also specify the table that includes this column. If it is (which I do not assume) specify which column it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select distinct p.team, (
Select count(*) from Player where team=p.team
) 
from Player p
```

Output would be(e.g):

- Team1 25
- Team2 34
- Team3 11

Answer (score 2):

depending on what you want you can do

```
select team, count(PlayerID) as NoOfPlayers
from Player
where team = 'Lackers'
```

or

```
select team, count(PlayerID) as NoOfPlayers
from Player
group by team
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `GROUP BY team` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT team,COUNT(playerID) As NoOfPlayers from Player group by team
```

[image]